# React: How do I make a video play only as the user scrolls, then move to other content?

Tags: reactjs, video, scroll

Using React, I need to allow a user to scroll through a video, or back by scrolling back. While they are scrolling the video, it should stay fully in frame. When they reach the end of the video, it should allow them to scroll down to other content on the page. (Example behavior, though I think the implementation is different: https://orangecomet.com/)

I have tried a couple of libraries such as Scrollyvideo, but nothing has worked. For example, the React Scrollyvideo import does not stay locked in frame but scrolls past the video while playing it. I don't know how to fix that; its default position is already sticky.

This is a semi-working thing I got, trying to convert [this](https://codepen.io/marduklien/pen/MdvdEG) to React, but it's not at all good because it doesn't allow anything to appear below it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const ScrollVideo = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const playbackConst = 500;
  const videoLength = 10;
  const videoHeight = `${videoLength * playbackConst}px`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const vid = videoRef.current;

    const scrollPlay = () => {
      const frameNumber = window.scrollY / playbackConst;
      vid.currentTime = frameNumber;

      window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="set-height" style={{ height: videoHeight }}>
        <video
          id="v0"
          tabIndex={0}
          // autoBuffer="autobuffer"
          preload="preload"
          ref={videoRef}
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0, 
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <source
            type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'
            src="/neural.mp4"
          ></source>
        </video>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ScrollVideo;
```

And this actually does what I want it to, except I need to change it to only start the behavior when the top of the video is in frame; but it relies on scrollbar hijacking, which is apparently near-taboo:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const ScrollVideo = () => {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const playerRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (playerRef.current && duration) {
      const currentTime = playerRef.current.getCurrentTime();
      let newTime = currentTime + e.deltaY * 0.02;

      if (newTime <= 0) {
        playerRef.current.seekTo(0, "seconds");
      } else if (newTime >= duration) {
        playerRef.current.seekTo(duration, "seconds");
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        playerRef.current.seekTo(newTime, "seconds");
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll, { passive: false });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [duration]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={playerRef}
        url="neural.mp4"
        width="80%"
        height="80%"
        onDuration={setDuration}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScrollVideo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a Typescript working version with some AI help and tweaking. This includes a feature to autoplay video, but if user begins scrolling, stop autoplay permanently for this page load and let user scroll video back and forth. Simpler implementations could cut down on the code.

NOTE: This will not look smooth unless you use a video encoded for scrolling. Directions for that below scrolling code.

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface ScrollVideoProps {
  src: string;
  heightPerSecond: number;
  CoverElement?: React.ReactNode;
  belowNav: boolean;
}

const ScrollVideo: React.FC<ScrollVideoProps> = ({
  src,
  heightPerSecond,
  CoverElement,
  belowNav = false,
}) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState("400vh"); // Default value
  const [videoEnded, setVideoEnded] = useState(false);

  const onVideoEnd = () => {
    setVideoEnded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let lastScroll = window.scrollY;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (!videoRef.current || !containerRef.current) return;

      const containerTop = containerRef.current.offsetTop;
      const containerHeight = containerRef.current.offsetHeight;
      const containerBottom = containerTop + containerHeight;

      const scrollPos = window.scrollY;
      const viewportBottom = scrollPos + window.innerHeight;

      // Check if video is within the viewport
      const isVideoInView =
        containerTop < viewportBottom && containerBottom > scrollPos;

      if (isVideoInView && !videoRef.current.paused) {
        videoRef.current.pause();
      }

      const percentageScrolled = (scrollPos - containerTop) / containerHeight;
      if (Number.isFinite(percentageScrolled) && videoRef.current.duration) {
        const targetTime = percentageScrolled * videoRef.current.duration;

        // Override autoplay when scrolling down, starting from autoplayed time if it exceeds scrolled amount. Same but opposite for scrolling up
        if (
          (videoRef.current.currentTime < targetTime &&
            scrollPos > lastScroll) ||
          (videoRef.current.currentTime > targetTime && scrollPos < lastScroll)
        ) {
          videoRef.current.currentTime = targetTime;
          setVideoEnded(false);
        }
      }

      lastScroll = window.scrollY;
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleVideoLoaded = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      setContainerHeight(`${videoRef.current.duration * heightPerSecond}px`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const videoElement = videoRef.current;
    if (videoElement) {
      if (videoElement.readyState >= 1) {
        handleVideoLoaded(); // Call directly if metadata is already loaded
      } else {
        videoElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleVideoLoaded);
      }

      return () => {
        videoElement.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleVideoLoaded);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      style={{
        height: containerHeight,
        width: "100%",
        position: "relative",
      }}
    >
      <video
        muted
        playsInline
        controls={false}
        autoPlay
        ref={videoRef}
        onEnded={onVideoEnd}
        style={{
          position: "sticky",
          top: belowNav ? "68px" : "0",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100vh",
          objectFit: "cover",
        }}
      >
        <source src={src} type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the
        video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScrollVideo;
```

How to encode a video for smooth scrolling:

1. Download/install FFMPEG (free).
2. In terminal, paste a command like the below. (The path should start from wherever ls returns. The first is your file location, and the ending path is the desired new file path/name.)

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/your/video/input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 22 -r 60 -g 1 -keyint_min 1 -sc_threshold 0 /path/to/your/video/input-encoded.mp4
```